# Flutter Font Awesome Icons Not Showing

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I changed version , I did this steps ;

1. Stopping the app
2. Running flutter clean in your app directory
3. Deleting the app from your simulator / emulator / device
4. Rebuild & Deploy the app.

I tried everything but my font awesome package for flutter doesn't work.

**pubspec.yaml file**

[image: This is pubspec.yaml]

**Widget file**

[image: This is the line which i use command]

Comment: After flutter clean and pub get, then restart your ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Try following steps:

1. run `flutter pub get` in your terminal
2. Stop your App
3. Restart your app and see the result output

pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
```

Widget:

```
     Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
              ),
            ),
```

Your result: [image]

Comment: @demonjoseph most welcome if your problem is solved by my answer so accept and upvote it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code

EX:

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

 FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.venus,size: 50.0,),
```

[image] 
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is here for another FontAwesome icons issue - some icons does not work on Flutter when entered exact name. Naming convention is different for long 2-3 words named icons on Flutter package of FontAwesome. For example, `solar-panel` icon should be entered as `solarPanel` on Flutter. It is same for all long 2-3 words named icons.

From package specification on pub.dev:

> Icon names # Icon names equal those on the official website, but are
> written in lower camel case. If more than one icon style is available
> for an icon, the style name is used as prefix, except for "regular".
> Due to restrictions in dart, icons starting with numbers have those
> numbers written out.